# Charge distribution around ring such that electric field is zero along diameter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

"Design the charge distribution along a ring to make the electric field along its horizonatal diameter AB zero. The total charge is Q"

Considering the electric field needs to be zero along the whole diameter, the charge distribution would have to be zero at A and B. I have (slightly handwavingly) reasoned that the distribution must be somewhat sinusoidal, so I have used polar coordinates (as the ring and the charges are in one plane) to define the charge density

$$
\rho (r, \theta) = q\delta(r-R)sin^2(\theta)
$$
where the delta function ensures the charges are on the ring of radius $R$, and $sin^2(\theta)$ ensures an oscillating density that is zero at the points A and B. Then from the definition of the electric potential

$$
\Phi(\vec{x}) = \int \frac{\rho(\vec{x}')}{|\vec{x} - \vec{x}'|} d^3x'
$$
I found a function of $\theta$ that gives the length of a point $a$ along the diameter AB to the point on the ring, satisying $|\vec{x} - \vec{x}'|$, but this makes the integral very messy, being

$$
\Phi(\vec{x}) = \int \frac{qsin^2(\theta)\delta(r-R)}{-a\left[ cos(\theta) - \sqrt{sin^2(\theta) + R^2/a^2} \right]} d^3x
$$

I'm not sure if my approach so far is at all correct (especially reducing this to 2 dimensions since it is completely defined in one plane), but any hints in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).